# How can I deploy Hyper-V updates [without pushing an entire VM]?

Tags: virtual-machines, hyper-v, deployment

I have a VM that is sent out to it's users. The users (on Win 8 Ent) can make changes, etc. but every quarter a new version of the 'base' VM comes out.

Right now, the plan is to send out full copies of the 250GB+ VMs... Yikes!

I am fantasizing about a way to push just the changes to the 'base' image since the previous release 3 moths previous. I am currently managing this with another Win 8 Ent machine, but have access to all the more feature rich versions if I need them (Undo Disks, Difference disks, etc.).

With users on all continents, how best to *not* push full 250GB+ exports?

*Note: I realize that local user changes to their image during the period between releases will be lost. I have accounted for that already (save or delete!)... I'm only talking here strictly about the 'base' image updates being pushed out... :)*

Comment: try to ask a simple question, don't mix your feeling or opinion in it. Also be a lot shorter - people would like to quickly read what you are asking.

Comment: Please feel free to edit to suit.

Comment: thanks, but i am not an expert in the topic, so i might risk contaminating your question. consider my comment as an advice, and try to do it yourself